# How to remove blank/empty page for docx file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, docx

How to remove blank or empty page for docx file using python ?

Expecting to remove blank or empty page from docs file. i have tried with python docx library and many more library to remove empty or blank  page from ms word file.

Comment: Word does not work with pages as such. You need to know why the page is there and blank. See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BlankPage.htm and https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html.